# How to create SharePoint Solution?

Tags: sharepoint, installation, wspbuilder

I'm new to SharePoint and I'm creating a public website using SharePoint Server 2007.

**I want to create solution or installer of my SharePoint website to copy it to another server other then my local machine.**

Anyone helps me out to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you know SharePoint, I'd advise looking at the SharePoint extension for Visual Studio at [Microsoft downloads](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=fb9d4b85-da2a-432e-91fb-d505199c49f6)

Comment: Hi Timores, I have already installed "VSeWSS 1.3". But i dont know how to create installer for my Public SharePoint site.

I'm using SharePoint designer for designing webpages. How can I copy all of my webpages to other server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at [SharePoint Installer](http://www.codeplex.com/sharepointinstaller). Very useful to create installer .exe from a SharePoint Solution. Especially useful if you use [WSPBuilder](http://www.codeplex.com/wspbuilder).

With these 2 tools, you can create a setup project in no time at all (2 steps).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now I'm using both of it.